# image refrence on the document.write function disable, wont dissipear when function enabled

Tags: javascript

when using the document write calling an image in function disable, wont dissapear function enabled..

I tried adding document.write('<img style="border-radius: 5px; margin-top: -190px; width: 170px;" src="images/notreadypulse.gif">'); to function disable, assuming that when function enable begins after 300000 ms that the image in document write would go away, any suggestions would be great, perhaps im missing something here.

```
<script>
  const refreshBtn = document.getElementById("refresh");
  refreshBtn.addEventListener("click", refresh);
  disable();

 
  function disable() {
    // If `disableRefresh` is truthy...
    if (localStorage.getItem("disableRefresh")) {
      // ...Disables the button and re-enables it after 2 seconds
      refreshBtn.setAttribute("disabled", ""); // Any value makes it true
      setTimeout(enable, 300000); // JavaScript measures times in milliseconds
    //display image when disabled
    document.write('<div class="notready"><img style="border-radius: 5px; margin-top: -190px; width: 170px;" src=\"images/notreadypulse.gif\"></div>');
    }
  }

  function enable() {
    // Removes (boolean) `disabled` attribute and (string) `disableRefresh` item
    refreshBtn.removeAttribute("disabled");
    localStorage.removeItem("disableRefresh")
   
   
  }

  function refresh() {
    // Sets `disableRefresh` to a truthy value, and refreshes the page
    localStorage.setItem("disableRefresh", "yep");
    location = location;
    $.get("./dailybonus.php");
    
  };
</script>
```

Comment: [Stop using `document.write`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/802854/1048572)!

Comment: Thank you, I am now using document.getElementById